# Can I use a global variable in my controller

Tags: php, phalcon

Hello I am new to Phalcon, having trouble with global variables in a controller.
 I have a controller with a global variable `$mobs` , this is it.

```
class ControllerBase extends Controller {
public $mobs;

public function initialize() {
    $user = $this -> session -> get("uid");
    $user = Users::findFirstByu_id($user);
    if ($user != null) {
        if ($user -> f_id != null) {
            $mobs = Mob::find(array("f_id=$user->f_id", "order" => "m_id"));
        }
    }
}
}
?>
```

According to my understanding I can set this and call it from an action eg.

```
public function mobsAction() {
  foreach ($mobs as $mob) {
    echo $mob->m_displayname;
  }
}
```

but this gives me an `Undefined variable: mobs error`

I am wondering if it is possible to use a variable like this, or if i should just have the initialise code in each action.

Comment: You can access the `$mobs` with `$this` pseudo-variable anywhere in the class. Like `$this->mobs`. Read more about [Class Properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im guessing that you are trying to set the class variable $mobs in the initialize function and then trying to iterate through them in the class function mobsAction, to access the class variable mobs youll need to use $this->mobs instead of $mobs, like this:

```
class ControllerBase extends Controller {
  public $mobs;

  public function initialize() {
      $user = $this -> session -> get("uid");
      $user = Users::findFirstByu_id($user);
      if ($user != null) {
          if ($user -> f_id != null) {
              $this->mobs = Mob::find(array("f_id=$user->f_id", "order" => "m_id"));
          }
      }
  }

  public function mobsAction() {
    foreach ($this->mobs as $mob) {
      echo $mob->m_displayname;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works. I tried this before posting and was getting an error `Cannot access empty property mobs`. My mistake was using `$this->$mobs = $stuff` instead of `$this->mobs = $stuff`